# WiX Make a Sub-Dir a Component Group when running heat

Tags: xslt, wix, wix3.5, wix3.7

Hello all my fellow WiX'ers,

I was wondering if it possible, and if so where I can go to learn how to do it, to run heat on a directory and have each directory inside that one be it's own Component Group.

Example:

- Root Directory

  - Sub Dir 1

    - Sub Sub Dir 1
    - Sub Sub Dir 2
    - Sub Sub Dir 3
  - Sub Dir 2

    - Sub Sub Dir 1
    - Sub Sub Dir 2
    - Sub Sub Dir 3
  - Sub Dir 3

    - Sub Sub Dir 1
    - Sub Sub Dir 2
    - Sub Sub Dir 3

Then run a heat command in the Build Event of the VS2010 project (example below):

```
heat dir "Root Directory" -gg -sfrag -srd -dr INSTALLFOLDER -out MyWXS.wxs
```

and then have that WXS file structured like so:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
   <Fragment>
      <DirecotryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
         <Directory Id="dir84156489" Name="Sub Dir 1"> ... </Directory>
         <Directory Id="dir84156489" Name="Sub Dir 2"> ... </Directory>
         <Directory Id="dir84156489" Name="Sub Dir 3"> ... </Directory>
     </DirectoryRed>
   </Fragment>
   <Fragment>
      <ComponentGroup Id="Sub Dir 1"> ... </ComponentGroup>
      <ComponentGroup Id="Sub Dir 2"> ... </ComponentGroup>
      <ComponentGroup Id="Sub Dir 3"> ... </ComponentGroup>
   </Fragment>
</wix>
```

If there is any confusion in my question or if anyone has any additional questions for me please let me know.  Thank you and I look forward to hearing from you.

**EDIT**
Using the following xslt file I am getting the WXS structure that follows after:

```
**XLST File**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
**WXS File Result**

<Wix>
   <Fragment>
      <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
         <Directory Id="dir846546" Name="SubDir1"> ... </Directory>
         <Directory Id="dir846546" Name="SubDir2"> ... </Directory>
         <Directory Id="dir846546" Name="SubDir3"> ... </Directory>
      </DirectoryRef>
   </Fragment>
   <wix:Fragment xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
      <wix:ComponentGroup Id="SubDur1"> ... </wix:ComponentGroup>
   </wix:Fragment>
   <wix:Fragment xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
      <wix:ComponentGroup Id="SubDur2"> ... </wix:ComponentGroup>
   </wix:Fragment>
   <wix:Fragment xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
      <wix:ComponentGroup Id="SubDur3"> ... </wix:ComponentGroup>
   </wix:Fragment>
</Wix>
```

No matter what I do I cannot get the Directories to be created as component groups...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heat can do an XSL transform before emitting its output. Just add the `-t transform.xsl` argument.

All that's needed is to append a few component groups to the output. Generate a component group by matching on a first-level directory and then referencing all of the descendent components.

See the XSL for my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17153157/2226988) to a similar question.

Comment: Thank you! This looks like it will do what I need it to but if you could take a look at the updated Question and let me know what it is I am doing wrong that would be great thanks!

Comment: You have a misspelling: DriectoryRef. I think you'll want almost exactly what I linked to but getting any result first is a step on the way to getting the right result 

Comment: okay I made the changes and the question is updated to reflect the new file

Comment: Now you have a ComponentGroup each for Sub Dir 1 and siblings, add ComponentGroupRef Id="SubDir1" etc to Feature elements as desired. When the installer installs a file for a component, it creates the directory subtree needed to place it. Components are already associated with a Directory with the structure that heat generates.