# WiX: How do I run heat.exe with a multi-folder setup to get multiple WXS files?

Tags: wix, installation, wix3.7

I have a source file setup something like this: **C:\Base**, and in Base is **FolderA**, **FolderB**, **FolderC**, etc.... I want to run "heat dir" on each sub-folder in Base, so that I get one WXS file containing one ComponentGroup for each folder.

If I run heat (from C:)

```
heat dir Base\FolderA -cg FolderAGroup -gg -scom -sreg -sfrag -dr -var var.SourceDir INSTALLDIR -out Components-FolderA.wxs
```

(or '**heat dir FolderA ...**' from C:\Base)

(Note that I'll run heat once per FolderA, FolderB, etc... from a script. I don't expect one heat statement to take care of all folders.)

```
Components-FolderA.wxs looks like this: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLDIR">
            <Directory Id="dirA..." Name="FolderA">
                <Component Id="cmpF..." Guid="{GUID-HERE}">
                    <File Id="filB..." KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\RandomFile.txt" />
                </Component>
            </Directory>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="FolderAGroup">
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpF..." />
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

The problem with this is that **Source="$(var.SourceDir)\RandomFile.txt** uses whatever I specify as **SourceDir**. So if I designate C:\Base as **SourceDir**, the file RandomFile.txt can't be found because it's looking for C:\Base\RandomFile.txt, not C:\Base\FolderA\RandomFile.txt. I can't specify C:\Base\FolderA as **SourceDir** because FolderB, FolderC, etc... will be wrong. **So how do I tell heat to insert 'FolderA\' in between '$(var.SourceDir)\' and 'RandomFile.txt'**?

I have looked at [Harvesting multiple directories in WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108287/harvesting-multiple-directories-in-wix/), but the first answer is too much manual work (we're lookong for almost complete automation) and the second answer puts everything in one file under one ComponentGroup, which would be a maintenance nightmare as we have thousands of files and dozens of folders and sub-folders to be installed.

Comment: What about running heat from within C:\Base?  e.g. `cd c:\Base & heat dir .`...

Comment: I tried that (see my comment under the first heat statement) and get the exact same output.

Comment: I found a less than ideal workaround: use a different -var arg to specify the source folder with each heat call. This means manually keeping track of every FolderA B C, etc..., as well as a few others, so I'd really like to hear if there is a better (automated) way to deal with this.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what I think you're calling the [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17153157/2226988). The idea is to create a `ComponentGroup` for each child folder, right? That's what the XSL does. Do you really need it broken up into different .wxs files?

Comment: Yes, I need separate WXS files. We have way too many source files to keep track of in one WXS file.